# How can I detect the user's language and redirect to a language appropriate webpage?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect the user's language settings, then redirect her based on that. If the user has `pl` as her default language setting, she should be redirected to `polish.html`. If `ru`, then `russian.html`. Otherwise, `english.html`.

```
a = navigator.language;
b = navigator.userLanguage;

language = (a && !b)? a.toLowerCase() : b;

pl = 'pl';
ru = 'ru';
en = 'en'||'us'||'au'||'bz'||'ca'||'gb'||'ie'||'jm'||'nz'||'tt'||'za';

switch (language) {
  case pl: window.location.replace('polish.html'); break;
  case ru: window.location.replace('russian.html'); break;
  case en: window.location.replace('english.html'); break;
}
```

In general, the above script works, except for one problem: the browser continually refreshes the page. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are continually reloading the page, regardless of your current state. If your user's language is English and you're on `english.html`, there's no reason to reload the page.

```
var language = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).toLowerCase(),
    // simpler way of getting the user's language (take advantage of || in JS)
    en = [ "en", "us", "au", "bz", "ca", "gb", "ie", "jm", "nz", "tt", "za" ],
    // we'll need an array of the languages associated with English
    currentPage = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

if (language == "pl" && currentPage.indexOf("polish") == -1) {
    // if the user's language is polish and the page's link doesn't contain polish
    // in it, redirect the user to polish.html
    window.location.replace("polish.html");
} else if (language == "ru" && currentPage.indexOf("russian") == -1) {
    // same concept as above
    window.location.replace("russian.html");
} else if (en.indexOf(language) > -1 && currentPage.indexOf("english") == -1) {
    // here, we're checking whether their language is in the array
    // of user languages that should default to english
    window.location.replace("english.html");
}
```

You can even simplify the above logic by removing `en.indexOf(language) > -1` from the last `else if` statement. This'll make the default landing page `english.html`.